# What is wrong in this VB.Net call to C win32 dll

Tags: c, vb.net, windows

Is this the correct signature for VB

```
<DllImportAttribute("MyDll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Private Shared Function GetOrderingCodeCassetteCasing(<Out()> ByVal OrderingCode As    StringBuilder,ByVal OrderingCodeElements As Integer) As Integer

extern "C" int __stdcall GetOrderingCodeCassetteCasingW(LPWSTR OrderingCode,int OrderingCodeElements)
```

The C functions copies information to the OrderingCode, I create a StringBuilder size 100 and passes it to the dll. I have tried string, stringbuilder, byref, byval,  etc. And all my result i get this

A call to PInvoke function 'RohexTest!RohexTest.Econovent::GetOrderingCodeCassetteCasing' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: There is no obvious mistake here.  The only thing that I can think of is that the author of this code changed the function and didn't tell you about it.  Send him a small repro project to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: If that is the C declaration, I would think that the `OrderingCodeElements` argument should be `Short` instead of `Integer` in the VB declaration.  The same for the return value.